# WP7 Application Bar Icons not showing on Simulator (but works in Blend)

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

It is most probably a stupid mistake, but can anyone tell me why my icons are showing in Blend, but not in the simulator (and not in VS10, but that's not really an issue)?

[image: WP7 Application Bar Icons. Blend (left), Simulator (right)]

**Edit** - Here is my XAML :

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/share.png" Text="Partager"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.edit.rest.png" Text="Note"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.feature.camera.rest.png" Text="Photos/Vidéos"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/calendar.png" Text="Rendez-vous"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems> 
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

My four .png files are 48x48, transparent .png with *black* foreground, since the `appbar.*.rest.png` files where like that and found in the Microsoft icons folder

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Make sure that the image properties '**build to action**' is **Content**.

Comment: i was just about to say that, this is the answer to most of the "i can't see the app bar icon" questions

Comment: I tried this but it didn't solve the problem, would you have any other suggestions? (I rebuilt and cleaned the solution before trying)

Answer (score 3):

Are your icons:

- Transparent with a white foreground
- The right size (48x48)
- PNGs

? If so, that should be fine. What does your XAML look like?

Comment: I updated my question, the foreground is black, but otherwise everything is like you said. I found two of these icons in Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Icons, so I don't think the black foreground is the issue...

Comment: @Thomas: Well, the documentation specifically says that the foreground should be white IIRC, so it's at least worth trying that.

Comment: My problem was solved using the build action, but indeed, I should have put a white foreground image then. But when a button is highlighted (clicked), it becomes white and then I would need to change the image, right ? I'm supposed to do that programmatically ?

Comment: @Thomas: No, you don't need to do anything - the system handles things like rotating it etc.

Comment: Yep, I so that, and changing the color with the theme. But I mean, when the user's finger taps the button, and hold it there, the background changes to white, and the icon doesn't change colour

Comment: @Thomas: The icon foreground *should* change to black (i.e. it's a white filled in circle with your icon as black on top). That's certainly what happens with my app, and I didn't need to do anything for that to happen.

Comment: Well, I created an empty project, uncommented the tabbar code and set a system icon in Blender, and it's not working. You can dl the archive here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3475545/AppBar.zip or see my solution here : http://db.tt/gSenDVE

Comment: @Thomas: I'll see if I can have a look tonight.