# Why won't the images show in my WP7 App?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Common image questions in regards to developing WP7 applications which are all related to the same issue of Build Action.

- Why won't my images show in my WP7 app?
- Why aren't the Application Icon buttons showing in my WP7 app?
- Why aren't the images showing up in my *CONTROL-NAME* control?
- Which path do I use to show my images, in examples I see two different ways?
- What is the difference between Content and Resource in Build Action property?
- What is "Build Action"?

**Side Note** I've been seeing these questions (or question) over, and over again. When you start seeing it every 4 or 5 questions, I think there's something wrong. Perhaps someone could turn this into a Community Wiki so we can keep future WP7 questions relevant and more unique?

Thanks.

Comment: Just pick one of those questions and provide it with an extensive answer. That might to turn it into Wiki.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would come up if they start asking the question. It's just the way they phrase them previously makes it sound like its some kind of rare circumstance why their images don't show when its all the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why won't my images show in my WP7 app?

[Set source to image in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/840cefd2-ff80-4c6b-80a6-5eee792ef78a)

> Why aren't the Application Icon buttons showing in my WP7 app?

[WP7 Application Bar Icons not showing on Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266225/wp7-application-bar-icons-not-showing-on-simulator-but-works-in-blend)

> Which path do I use to show my images, in examples I see two different
>   ways?

[Images and Build Action settings in WP7](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/images-and-build-actio-settings-in-wp7/)

> What is the difference between Content and Resource in the Build
>   Action property?

[WP7 working with Images: Content vs Resource build action.](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action)

> What is "Build Action"

[File Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx)